# When I tried uploading a file to Google using Google APIs, I received 403 error

Tags: ios, google-api, google-drive-api

Please help, here is my code :

```
NSData * fileContent = [@"ahcnuefewfewfsnjcdsjc"     dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
GTLRUploadParameters * uploadParameters = [GTLRUploadParameters uploadParametersWithData:fileContent MIMEType:@"text/plain"];
GTLRDrive_File * driveFile = [GTLRDrive_File new];
driveFile.name = @"First blood.txt";

GTLRDriveQuery_FilesCreate * query = [GTLRDriveQuery_FilesCreate queryWithObject:driveFile uploadParameters:uploadParameters];
query.fields = @"279683368406-cegfq720t7oe4j912m88pvl5qqbkv022.apps.googleusercontent.com";
self.driveService = [ GTLRDriveService new];
self.driveService.authorizer = self.authorization;

[self.driveService executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLRServiceTicket * _Nonnull callbackTicket, id  _Nullable object, NSError * _Nullable callbackError) {

    if (!callbackError) {
        NSLog(@"---upLoad File Success---");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"---upLoad File fail---");
    }
}];
```

Comment: This error also occurs if you disable the Google Drive setting called "Allow users to install Google Drive apps". This might be a good thing to check if you are certain that Google Drive is already enabled.

Comment: Please post the full error you are getting. Not just the number.

Comment: @HarshalValanda and DaImTo, thanks,  I have solved the problem by myself,  I just changed the scopes to " kGTLRAuthScopeDrive" in OIDAuthorizationRequest , then my issue is fixed.